# Configuar exportação de um EPS para JPEG no Magick.NET

Tags: c#, imagemagick

Estou utilizando a biblioteca [Magick.NET](https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET/tree/master/Documentation) para converter um arquivo EPS > JPEG. Porém o resultado não está sendo agradável pois independente da resolução(DPI) e size(Width e Height) que eu coloco a imagem sai pixelada e com as cores erradas... Segue exemplo:

Imagem salva no Photoshop:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Imagem salva via Magick.NET
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por ser um vetor, o correto seria salva-la em qualquer dimensão **com qualidade** porém não é o que está acontecendo. Segue o código que estou utilizando.

```
using (MagickImage _image = new MagickImage(image.Path))
{
     _image.Resize(3000, 3000); //Maior lado = 3000px
     _image.Density = new Density(300); //Set DPI = 300
     _image.Write("teste.jpeg"); //
}
```

Existe alguma configuração ou parâmetro que eu deva passar para melhorar essa resolução e correção das cores de forma que fique IGUAL ao EPS?

Answer (score 3):

Para ter uma boa qualidade é necessário configurar o arquivo antes de importa-lo através do `MagickReadSettings`:

```
 MagickReadSettings settings = new MagickReadSettings();
 settings.ColorSpace = ColorSpace.sRGB;
 settings.Format = MagickFormat.Eps;
 settings.Compression = Compression.LosslessJPEG;
 settings.Density = new Density(300);

 using (MagickImage _image = new MagickImage())
 {
     _image.Read(image.Path, settings);
     _image.Write("teste.jpg");
 }
```

Novo resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]